# Web application cannot access API server in same cluster

Tags: reactjs, node.js, kubernetes

Developing a node.js API server and web client application to display gathered data (details below).

Node.js API server and node.js web client application work well running on development machine outside of cluster.  Built as two images (based on node:alpine-lts), the pair run well on Docker outside of cluster.

Problem: With images deployed into cluster, the API Server works as expected (with service defined for internal use), but the Web Client application fails to connect to the API Server.  Ingress configured to allow access to Web Client from outside of cluster.  Web Display (Client app) cannot resolve name of API Server, and fails to load data. Response from react "Failed to fetch", and error response in browser console of "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

From command line of Web client app pod - I can ping the API server via its service name, and can successfully 'curl' the API Server endpoint and received valid response/data. Both http://nodeapiserver.default:3000/environment and http://nodeapiserver:3000/environment work via curl.  The API server is running, and the service is registered with the cluster DNS. Don't understand how I can resolve from the command line, but not from within the app?

Comment: Web apps run in the browser. The URL for your API must be available to the client device

Comment: Spot on Phil!  I just had that epiphany myself about 10 minutes ago - doh! Exposed the API outside the cluster, and voila - it works! (ok, it worked after I found _all_ of the places I needed to correct my mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Phil, the web app runs in the browser.  The URL for the API must be exposed.

Added an ingress for the API, and adjusted the Web App endpoint to the new ingress (instead of the internal address), and works a charm!